# Как процессор определяет что делать с командой?

Tags: железо, процессор

У меня вопрос очень очень низкого уровня, в процессоре есть разные разделы под разные операции, он берёт инструкцию и как он понимает что куда, я имею ввиду на уровне материнки или того где он определяет где ему обрабатывать

И ещё раз но кратко так как я плохо объясняю: как и где процессор определяет куда сувать команду

Comment: Возьмите спецификацию на **конкретный** процессор и разбирайтесь в ней. Пока у вас очень какой-то не конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Тут явно нужен ликбез. Почитайте книжку "introduction to computing systems" patt and patel, там как раз разжовывают все начиная с битов и логических цепей, через учебный процессор до ассемблера и высокоуровнего кода.

Comment: @CrazyElf но у разных процессоров должны быть какие-нибудь общие принципы, наверное?

Comment: (интересно, способствует ли [постройка процессора в майнкрафте](https://www.pcworld.com/article/559794/8-bit-computer-processor-built-in-minecraft-can-run-its-own-games.html) пониманию этих принципов)

Comment: Если под "куда сувать команду" вы подразумеваете, какое исполнительное устройство (функциональный блок, например, устройство чтения-записи памяти или сумматор или умножитель с плавающей точкой), должно ее обработать, то этот выбор делается по коду операции (несколько бит в теле команды) и он (выбор) зашит в электрическую схему процессора (в ту ее часть, куда поступает очередная команда, выбираемая из памяти)

Comment: В х86 макс.длина одной инструкций = 16 байт. Из озу пачками по 64-байта эти инструкции поступают в кэш, и далее в декодер инструкций, который по первому байту вычисляет длину текущей инструкции, и прихватывает остальные её байты. Теперь декодер разбивает инструкцию на несколько микро-операций mops, и передаёт их в исполнительные устройства процессора, где они и отрабатывают свои задачи.

Comment: `как и где процессор определяет куда сувать команду` кмк вам стоит почитать это https://habr.com/ru/articles/556098/ там вроде не плохо всё объясняется(особенно стоит обратить внимание на параграф про АЛУ)